# MySQL: Fetch conditional rows only, from a query dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Please update title as I didn't got any suitable one and remove this comment ;)

I have a table having data like:

<kbd>id</kbd><kbd>assigned_to</kbd><kbd>foreign_id</kbd><kbd>purchase_date</kbd>

<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>5</kbd>                 
<kbd>1</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-01</kbd>    


<kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>                 
<kbd>1</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-09</kbd>    


<kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd>                 
<kbd>1</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-10</kbd>    


<kbd>8</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd>                 
<kbd>1</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-13</kbd>    


<kbd>12</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>                 
<kbd>2</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-13</kbd>    


<kbd>18</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>                 
<kbd>3</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-13</kbd>

I want to retrieve rows from this data for `foreign_id=1` AND `assigned_to=7` if row exists for `assigned_to=7,

else row having latest `purchase_date` for `foreign_id=1` **irrespective of assigned_to=7**;

Result Set:

<kbd>id</kbd><kbd>assigned_to</kbd><kbd>foreign_id</kbd><kbd>purchase_date</kbd>



**CASE I : IF ASSIGNED_TO=7 AND FOREIGN_ID=1**

<kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd>                 
<kbd>1</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-09</kbd>    


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------




**CASE 2: IF ASSIGNED_TO=7 AND FOREIGN_ID=2**

<kbd>12</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>                 
<kbd>2</kbd>             
<kbd>2014-01-13</kbd>

Please give a MySQL query for fetching requirements. Whatever way I thought, or my SQL knowledge ;) I got either only row having assigned_to=7, or nothing if assigned_to=X[x=other assigned users and other other foreign_ids] isn't present in table.

Comment: What you are looking for SQL query? what have you tried so far?

Comment: yes I am looking for sql query. I don't want to do it through PHP. Whatever I tried isn't working that's why I asked.

Comment: @Naveen hope my edit shows more clearer requirement :D

Comment: You confused me more now. What about the result when there is no ASSIGNED_TO=7 ?

Comment: Result Set's case 2,3 shows this only. If there is no assigned_id match but foreign_id matches then it gives showed result for case 2 and case 3.

Comment: In case 2,3 there is matching ASSIGNED_TO !! There is no difference in your all 3 result set, showed above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45341/discussion-between-aakash-sahai-and-naveen)

Comment: Sorry Aakash, i won't be able to chat now. Try to update your question properly. Did you understand my answer? Try to explain using that, what else you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the filter on `foreign_id` into the `WHERE` clause and the filter on `assigned_to` into the `ORDER BY` clause and add LIMIT 1, like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  assigned_to,
  foreign_id,
  purchase_date
FROM
  atable
WHERE
  foreign_id = @foreign_id
ORDER BY
  assigned_to = @assigned_to DESC,
  purchase_date              DESC
LIMIT 1
;
```

where `@foreign_id` and `@assigned_to` are query arguments.

The query will first find all rows matching the `@foreign_id`. Then it will divide them into two subsets:

1) rows matching the `@assigned_to`;
2) all the others.

The `@assigned_to` subset will be placed before the other subset and both will be additionally sorted in the descending order of `purchase_date`. Finally, the first row of the sorted dataset will be returned and the rest discarded.

As a result, the query returns the latest `@foreign_id`/`@assigned_to` match if it exists, or just the latest `@foreign_id` match otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. It was so simple and I was looking for this result. Nice explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use case...when in mysql with count() function.

Check out following link:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `IF ELSE` like below

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test where assigned_to = 7 AND foreign_id=1))
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM test
  WHERE foreign_id=1 AND assigned_to = 7
END
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM test WHERE foreign_id=1 AND purchase_date = (select MAX(purchase_date) from test)
```

Comment: Have a look at updated question. Not able to use your query. For using this do I need to create procedure?

Comment: No need to write SP. You can just run this in DBMS.

Comment: I think your query isn't for MySQL.

Comment: How you are running this SQL? Whatever i used keywords exists in mysql. Is it giving any error for you?

Comment: No its not working. I am using SELECT CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END statement. But this query working when only 1 column is fetched and I was looking for whole row.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Aakash Try this query...

```
select * from (
select * from tbl_purchase where foreign_id=1 AND assigned_to = 7 
union
(select * from tbl_purchase where foreign_id=1 order by purchase_date desc limit 1)
) as t limit 1
```